Failed to execute goal com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-maven-plugin:2.39.0:apply
I'm trying to run mvn clean install in IntelliJ and I get the following error. The project structure jdk is set to 17.
Failed to execute goal com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-maven-plugin:2.39.0:apply
Execution format-sources of goal com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-maven-plugin:2.39.0:apply failed: 
Unable to load the mojo 'apply' in the plugin 'com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-maven-plugin:2.39.0' due to an API incompatibility: 
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com/diffplug/spotless/maven/SpotlessApplyMojo 
has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Any ideas? I upgraded maven, java. I'm pretty stuck here.
I tried this as well:
mvn spotless:apply


I had the same problem, and it was just my JAVA_HOME variable that was set to Java 1.8. Apparently, Maven was using this JDK to run the plugin. I just set it to a more recent version and rebooted my PC.
